# How is RTABMap a SLAM algorithm if it has separate mapping and localization modes?

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, ros-melodic, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe the RTABMAP has `mapping` and `localization` modes. Can they both run together? If they can't how is RTABMap said to be a SLAM algorithm?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382085/how-is-rtabmap-a-slam-algorithm-if-it-has-separate-mapping-and-localization-modes?/) by [electrophod](https://answers.ros.org/users/43169/electrophod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2021-07-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

the mapping mode (default) in RTAB-Map is actually the SLAM mode (loop closures are detected online and graph is optimized online). The localization mode is really a localization mode (the map is not modified).

It applies for all other SLAM algorithms too. For example with GMapping/AMCL tutorials, you would say that you use gmapping for the mapping phase, then use AMCL for the localization phase. In reality, the mapping phase is doing SLAM.

Here other examples where "mapping" means SLAM:

- https://www.clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/kinetic/ros/ROS%20Navigation%20Basics.html
- http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/TIAGo/Tutorials/Navigation

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2021-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [electrophod](https://answers.ros.org/users/43169/electrophod/) on 2021-07-09**:
@matlabbe Thanks a lot for your reply. That perfectly answers my question!